# Best way to lazily collapse multiple contiguous items of a sequence into a single item

Tags: clojure

[Note: Title and text were heavily edited to make it more clear that I'm not particularly after strings, but after general sequences, and lazy processing of same]

Using character sequences / strings as an example, say I want to turn a string like

> "\t a\r      s\td  \t \r \n          f \r\n"

into

> " a s d f "

In more general terms, I want to turn all contiguous whitespace (or any other arbitray set of items) in a sequence into a single item, and that lazily.

I've come up with the following **partition-by/mapcat combo**, but wonder if there are easier or otherwise better ways (readability, performance, anything) to accomplish the same thing.

```
(defn is-wsp?
  [c]
  (if (#{\space \tab \newline \return} c) true))

(defn collapse-wsp
  [coll]
  (mapcat
   (fn [[first-elem :as s]]
     (if (is-wsp? first-elem) [\space] s))
   (partition-by is-wsp? coll)))
```

In action:

```
=> (apply str (collapse-wsp "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n"))
" a s d f "
```

**Update**:
I used strings / character sequences / wsp, as an example, but what I actually want is a generic function on sequences of any type that collapses arbitrary numbers of contiguous items, which are part of a predefined set of items, by some single predefined item. I'm particularly interested to know if there are better alternatives to partition-by/mapcat, not so much if this can be optimized for the  'string' special case.

**Update 2**:

Here's a fully lazy version - the one above isn't fully lazy, I fear, apart from that it is doing redundant is-wsp? checks. I generalized the parameter names etc. so it doesn't just look like something you could easily replace by a String.whatever() call - it's about arbitrary sequences.

```
(defn lazy-collapse
  ([coll is-collapsable-item? collapsed-item-representation] (lazy-collapse coll is-collapsable-item? collapsed-item-representation false))
  ([coll is-collapsable-item? collapsed-item-representation in-collapsable-segment?]
  (let [step (fn [coll in-collapsable-segment?]
               (when-let [item (first coll)]
                 (if (is-collapsable-item? item)
                   (if in-collapsable-segment?
                     (recur (rest coll) true)
                     (cons collapsed-item-representation (lazy-collapse (rest coll) is-collapsable-item? collapsed-item-representation true)))
                   (cons item (lazy-collapse (rest coll) is-collapsable-item? collapsed-item-representation false)))))]
    (lazy-seq (step coll in-collapsable-segment?)))))
```

This is fast, fully lazy, but I'd like to be able to express that more concisely, as I am quite lazy myself.

**Benchmarks of the lazy collapsers so far**:
Whether the code is readable or not is easy to judge by looking at the code, but in order to see how they compare in terms of performance, here are my benchmarks. I first check if the function does what it is supposed to do, and then I spit out how long it takes to

1. create the lazy seq 1M times
2. create the lazy seq and take the first item 1M times
3. create the lazy seq and take the second item 1M times
4. create the lazy seq and take the last item (i.e. fully realize the lazy seq) 1M times

Tests 1 through 3 are meant to gauge the laziness at least a little bit.
I ran the test a couple of times, and there was no significant variation in the execution times.

```
user=> (map
   (fn [collapse]
     (println (class collapse) (str "|" (apply str (collapse test-str is-wsp? \space)) "|"))
     (time (dotimes [_ 1000000] (collapse test-str is-wsp? \space)))
     (time (dotimes [_ 1000000] (first (collapse test-str is-wsp? \space))))
     (time (dotimes [_ 1000000] (second (collapse test-str is-wsp? \space))))
     (time (dotimes [_ 1000000] (last (collapse test-str is-wsp? \space)))))
   [collapse-overthink collapse-smith collapse-normand lazy-collapse])

user$collapse_overthink | a s d f |
"Elapsed time: 153.490591 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 3064.721629 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 4337.932487 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 24797.222682 msecs"

user$collapse_smith | a s d f |
"Elapsed time: 141.474904 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 812.998848 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 2112.331739 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 10750.224816 msecs"

user$collapse_normand | a s d f |
"Elapsed time: 314.978309 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1423.779761 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1669.660257 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 8074.759077 msecs"

user$lazy_collapse | a s d f |
"Elapsed time: 169.906088 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 638.030401 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1195.445016 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 6050.945856 msecs"
```

Bottom line so far: The nicest code is slowest, the ugliest code is fastest. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to be this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully lazy solution, written in a recursive style:

```
(defn collapse [l p v]
  (cond
    (nil? (seq l))
    nil
    (p (first l))
    (lazy-seq (cons v (collapse (drop-while p l) p v)))
    :otherwise
    (lazy-seq (cons (first l) (collapse (rest l) p v)))))
```

`l` is the list, `p` is the predicate, and `v` is the value to replace subsequences that match the predicate with.

If you're after pure speed at the expense of readability, you can do this:

```
(defn collapse-normand2
  ([l p v]
    (lazy-seq (collapse-normand2 (seq l) p v nil)))
  ([l p v _]
    (when l
      (lazy-seq
        (let [f (first l)
              r (next l)]
          (if (p f)
            (cons v (collapse-normand2 r p v nil nil))
            (cons f (collapse-normand2 r p v nil)))))))
  ([l p v _ _]
     (when l
       (lazy-seq
         (let [f (first l)
               r (next l)]
           (if (p f)
             (collapse-normand2 r p v nil nil)
             (collapse-normand2 r p v nil)))))))
```

There's probably a way to make this more readable. It does very well on all 4 tests.

Comment: After almost a year now, let me accept your answer. It's not the fastest, but maybe a good compromise between performance and conciseness / readability.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my fastest solution so far: (basically the same as M Smith's, but no destructuring)

```
(defn collapse [xs pred rep]
  (when-let [x (first xs)]
    (lazy-seq 
      (if (pred x)
        (cons rep (collapse (drop-while pred (rest xs)) pred rep))
        (cons x (collapse (rest xs) pred rep))))))
```

Here's a prettier solution, but 3x (!) slower: (effectively the same as SuperHorst's initial version...)

```
(defn collapse [col pred rep]
  (let [f (fn [[x & more :as xs]] (if (pred x) [rep] xs))]
    (mapcat f (partition-by #(if (pred %) true) col))))
```

Mini-benchmark ([full code](https://github.com/overthink/misc/blob/master/collapse.clj#L59)) output:

```
$ clj collapse.clj 
     SuperHorst: "Elapsed time: 58535.737037 msecs"
      Overthink: "Elapsed time: 70154.744605 msecs"
        M Smith: "Elapsed time: 89484.984606 msecs"
   Eric Normand: "Elapsed time: 83121.309838 msecs"
```

Example:

```
(def test-str "\t a\r      s\td \t \r \n          f \r\n")
(def is-ws? #{\space \tab \newline \return})

user=> (apply str (collapse test-str is-ws? \space))
" a s d f "
```

Used on a different type of seq:

```
user=> (collapse (range 1 110) #(= 2 (count (str %))) \X)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \X 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109)
```

It's fully lazy:

```
user=> (type (collapse test-str is-ws? \space))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
user=> (type (collapse (range 1 110) #(= 2 (count (str %))) \X))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

---

Old buggy version:

```
(defn collapse-bug [col pred rep]
  (let [f (fn [x] (if (pred x) rep x))]
    (map (comp f first) (partition-by f col))))
```

The bug is that it eats consecutive items not matching `pred`.

Comment: +1 for readability, -1 for taking more than twice as much time as msmith's collapse and more than thrice as much time as my lazy-collapse, using "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n" as test sequence

Comment: I'll take a readability for speed trade-off 9 times out of 10 :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. If you need to really process tons of data fast, you will optimize spots like these. And in those cases improving execution time by a factor of 2 or 3 means a lot. But I asked for "readability, performance, anything", so this is one answer. I'm basically still waiting for the one answer "to rule them all", which combines readability with performance.

Comment: Found and fixed a bug in my solution.  Now 20% slower and the same as your initial version... I am going to investigate the perf a bit.  I'm curious about where all the time is going.

Comment: Be careful of checking whether the list is empty by the truth value of its first item. Yes, it works for lists of characters, but it does not work if nil or false are in the list. In those cases, the list will be truncated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use Java's `String` function `replaceAll` ?

```
user=> (.replaceAll "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n" "\\s+" " ")
" a s d f "
```

I think, that it's heavily optimized for such operations...

**Update**: updated version of answer after clarification:

```
(defn is-blank? [^Character c] (not (nil? (#{\space \tab \newline \return} c))))

(defn collapse [coll fun replacement]
  (first (reduce (fn [[res replaced?] el]
                   (if (fun el)
                     (if replaced?
                       [res replaced?]
                       [(conj res replacement) true])
                     [(conj res el) false]))
                 [[] false] coll)))

(def aa-str "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n")

user> (apply str (collapse aa-str is-blank? \space))
" a s d f "
```

It also works with other seqs:

```
user> (collapse [1 1 2 3 1 1 1 4 5 6 1 1] #(= % 1) 9)
[9 2 3 9 4 5 6 9]
```

Another performance optimization could be use of transients instead of standard sequences...

Comment: If all I want to do is what you do in your example, then that is perfect. However, my question was specifically about laziness and character sequences. I used strings / character sequences / wsp to create a simple example, but what I actually want to have is a generic function on sequences, that collapses items that are part of a predefined set of items by another single item. Will update the question accordingly to make that more clear.

Comment: I think, that we could use reduce, will try to make code sample some time later...

Comment: I updated answer with `reduce` version... Although we can try to make it more effective by optimizing `is-blank?` function, etc.

Comment: Hm... have you (time (dotimes [_ 500000] ...) it or something? If I bring my code into the same form (function parameters etc.) as yours, mine is noticeably faster - apart from being simpler. Btw, the ^Character hint is not buying you much, unless you get "paid by the character" :P

Comment: But more importantly, reduce is not lazy.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that reduce isn't lazy... But on my machine, my version is almost 2 times fast as your variant 13441.127001 vs. 24612.312583 msecs on 500000 repetitions... I also tried transient version, but it doesn't give much performance gain - 13152.928431 msecs

Comment: Alex, I got bitten by my own laziness... As my version was (partially) lazy, I should have enforced full realization of the seq when benchmarking - e.g. by means of (last (collapse-wsp .... If I do that, your version is actually 4 times faster than collapse-wsp. In the meantime, I added a fully lazy version to my question, which is not only lazy, but faster than my initial version and your reduce version.

Comment: I don't see how transients can help you when building lazy seqs - if you eagerly conj/assoc into a data structure, they'd probably make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully-lazy implementation that is a bit cleaner:

```
<!-- language: lang-clojure -->
(defn collapse [ss pred replacement]  
    (lazy-seq    
          (if-let [s (seq ss)]   
              (let [[f & rr] s]  
               (if (pred f)   
                   (cons replacement (collapse (drop-while pred rr) pred replacement))  
                   (cons f (collapse rr pred replacement)))))))
```

Comment: +1 for being easier to read, but it takes 30% more time than lazy-collapse when testing on "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n".

Answer (score 0):

Strings in clojure are Java Strings, so you cannot create a String lazily (meaning, you need to consume all the input to build the string).

You can create a character sequence lazily, though:

```
USER> (remove #(Character/isWhitespace %) "\t    a\r          s\td  \t \r \n         f \r\n")
(\a \s \d \f)
```

you can use a string or a seq as input here, since remove calls seq on its last argument.

Comment: he wants not to remove spaces completely, just replace several instances of whitespace character into one space...